# How do I deploy a JCA connector as an OSGI bundle

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, jca

Is it possible to deploy an JCA Connector as an OSGI Bundle in GlassFish like it works with EJBs?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer specific to Glashfish, but since I'm working mainly with Jboss which is also based on an OSGI container, I have made the assumption that as with JBOSS, in Glashfish you can write custom OSGI extensions and deploy them to the container.

Now a few topics concerning JCA adapters:

- JCA adapter's main purpose is to connect to legacy back ends, or to facilitate working with incompatible resources (custom threading, listening server sockets, File IO etc).
- To implement a JCA adapter depending from the functionality(inbound/outbound, transactions etc), you have to implement from a few lines, to a lot of stuff.
- An implementation of a JCA adapter is expected to be portable across containers exempting maybe a couple of deployment descriptors.
- A JCA adapter is deployed as a standard "rar" EE archive.

Now my understanding of OSGI is rather limited but the one or two things that I know are:

- The container uses OSGI modules (bundles) to load components on demand thus obtaining better startup time.
- Inside the container things like the web server, servlet engine, datasource  management, transactions etc are wired together as OSGI bundles.
- You can deploy a custom OSGI extension to a container and/or write plugins and extensions to existing modules.

Sο from my point of view I don't see much functional overlapping of OSGI over JCA and my answer is "Technically you cannot deploy a JCA adapter as a OSGI bundle since they obey different contracts and depending from the functionality of specific JCA adapter, this may be pointless".